# VueJs - Create card for all weeks with its data from array

Tags: vue.js

I want to show a card on my website for every week in my array. The first card will contain all data from week 29, second card all data from week 30. My array is structered like below (data not the same as in the picture):

```
weekArray { 
   0: {
    day: 'Monday',
    week: 29,
    month: 'July'
   },
   1: {
    day: 'Tuesday',
    week: 29,
    month: 'July'
    },
   2: {
    day: 'Saturday',
    week: 30,
    month: 'July'
   },
   3: {
    day: 'Monday',
    week: 31,
    month: 'July'
    },
   5: {
    day: 'Tuesday',
    week: 31,
    month: 'July'
   },
   6: {
    day: 'Wednesday',
    week: 31,
    month: 'July'
    },
   7: {
    day: 'Monday',
    week: 32,
    month: 'July'
   },
   8: {
    day: 'Friday',
    week: 32,
    month: 'July'
    },
   9: {
    day: 'Tuesday',
    week: 33,
    month: 'July'
    },
```

Right now I'm for looping the array by taking the length of the array, which will make a card of every  look like this:
[Link to screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/isWSn.png)

Can someone help me my question?

Comment: Can you provide some of your Vue logic?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide a Vue.js logic.

Anyhow you can convert your Object (It's not an Array) in a multilevel Object organized by week.

This is only a javascript code that you can use as template for your Vue.js script.

```js
// Convert Object in Array
const weekArrayConverted = Object.keys(weekObjectArray).map( k => weekObjectArray[k])

console.log(weekArrayConverted)

// Get unique weeks present in array
const weeks = [... new Set(weekArrayConverted.map(r => r.week))]

console.log(weeks)

// Build a multilevel object with this schema
// {
//     week: 30
//     elements: [...array of elements with week == 30]
}
const result = weeks.map( r => {
    return {
    week: r, 
    elements: [... weekArrayConverted.filter( e => e.week === r)]
  }
})

console.log(result)
```